# API KEY | Cuenta de servicio

Tags: java, android

Actualmente estoy obteniendo esta advertencia [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utilizo un servicio de  SafetyNet el cual tiene un metodo attest el cual me pide la api key pero no puedo ponerla directamente

```
 SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest(nonce, "APY KEY")
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse>() {}
```

porque me da el error segun lo que me sugieren es

- No incruste claves API directamente en el código. Las claves API que
  están incrustadas en el código pueden exponerse accidentalmente al
  público. Por ejemplo, puede olvidar eliminar las claves del código
  que comparte. En lugar de incrustar sus claves API en sus
  aplicaciones, almacénelas en variables de entorno o en archivos fuera
  del árbol de origen de su aplicación.

Como puedo agregar esta api key en una variable de entorno ? o en un archivo fuera del arbol de origen? talve sea simple pero soy bastante nuevo

Desde ya gracias

Agregandolo como Elenasys aun conservo el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto enlace de ayuda de Google

Intente usar la cuenta de servicio pero el metodo Attest recibe la api key no puedo hacer nada ante eso?

al hacer uso de la respuesta de Jorge con la nueva edicion aun conservo la advertencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Bruno, agregue 2 opciones, guardarla dentro de local.properties sería la opción ideal!, saludos!

Comment: @Elenasys te deje actualiza la info que me pediste

Answer (score 5):

Como indica el mensaje, no es seguro escribir en código directamente, **una opción  segura es guardar los valores de API KEY dentro del archivo `local.properties`**:

**API KEY en local.properties**

En tu archivo `app/build.gradle` agrega

```
android {
     ...
    
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "myAPI_KEY", "\"VALOR_API_KEY\"" 
        ...
    }
     ...
    
}
```

dentro del archivo local.properties agrega la entrada que define el valor de la API KEY :

```
VALOR_API_KEY="AIzaSy..............."
```

al final construye tu proyecto y podrás obtener de la clase `BuildConfig` el valor de la API KEY:

```
    String myApiKey = BuildConfig.myAPI_KEY;

 SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest(nonce, myApiKey)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse>() {}
```

---

- **Actualización:**

### **Si aún te muestra el aviso, la opción más segura es obtener el valor de la API Key desde el archivo [google-services.json](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file)**

Al habilitar "Android Device Verification API" en https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/ y se genera una API KEY:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora debes [**descargar el archivo `google-services.json`**](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=es-419), para esto ve a la [**Consola Firebase**](https://firebase.google.com/)

Descarga el archivo y agrégalo dentro de `/app` en tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora agrega el Firebase SDK:

El complemento de servicios de Google para Gradle carga el archivo `google-services.json` que acaba de descargar. Modifique sus archivos `build.gradle` para usar el complemento.

Agrega en el `build.gradle` que se encuentra en la raíz del proyecto (`<projecto>/build.gradle`):

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Agrega la linea
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}
```

Agrega en el build.gradle que se encuentra dentro del directorio /app del proyecto (`<proyectp>/app/build.gradle`):

```
dependencies {
  // Agrega la linea.
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}
...
// Agrega al final del archivo
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Debes asegura que la lectura del archivo `google-services.json` se realice de forma correcta ejecutando tu aplicación. En algunos casos debes eliminar la aplicación y volver a instalarla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora esta sería la forma de obtener el valor de la `API_KEY` desde el archivo `google-services.json`:

```
 //Obtiene valor de API KEY.
 String API_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);

 SafetyNet.getClient(this).attest(nonce, API_KEY)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse>() {}
```

Comment: me da error al hacer esto asi @Elenasys no me deja colocar  buildConfigField "String", "myAPI_KEY", VALOR_API_KEY

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag debe estar dentro del bloque defaultConfig que a su vez se encuentra dentro de android en el build.gradle donde defines el targetSdk, agrega tu build.gradle en el cual no lo acepta

Comment: ya pude hacerlo andar, necesite ponerlo directo y entre "/"asdas/""

Comment: buildConfigField "String", "myAPI_KEY", "\"APIKEY\""

Comment: Excelente @BrunoSosaFastTag , saludos!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95989/discussion-between-bruno-sosa-fast-tag-and-elenasys).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la edicion pero aun conservo la advertencia al subir la app de nuevo, esto parece no querer nada!

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag verificaste que la Api Key no esta presente en ningun otro archivo?

Comment: Gracias @sioesi,un gusto saber de tí. Bruno verifica lo que comenta sioesi, que no tengas en otro lugar definida la api, excepto en el archivo google-services.json

Comment: @Jorgesys en la advertencia me dice en que lugares tengo la api y me marca en la clase que hago  String API_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key); pero claro si es donde la levanto pero no tiene sentido

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTagel ¿valor de "google_api_key" no se tiene en Strings.xml verdad?, únicamente debe estar en google-services.json.

Comment: Si @Jorgesys solo esta en el google-services.json ; cuando le doy click sobre el recurso en la clase me mande como a un values.xml como temporal nose si eso te dice algo

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag si, es correcto, es el valor generado dentro de /builds, te sugiero regenerar la API KEY descargar el google-services.json nuevamente a tu proyecto, trata nuevamente ya que posiblemente la API KEY actual este marcada como "expuesta". Si puedes también decirme que dice en "Ubicaciones vulnerables" que indica en esta imagen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exw7X.png

Comment: si cree una nueva en realidad, y no muestro donde dice el paquete de la clase porque en relidad muestra el nombre de la clase que es el splash y como es de un cliente no muestro porque no puedo jorge!, aunque me tiene bastante mal este tema no poder solucionarlo porque es grave y sin esto no podemos salir a prod y como que nada lo sluciona

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag puedes también decirme que dice en "Ubicaciones vulnerables" que indica en esta imagen : i.stack.imgur.com/Exw7X.png