# ¿Cómo se oculta la Key de maps? Android no me deja publicar

Tags: android, app

al tratar de publicar mi app en android, me arroja una "advertencia". La advertencia es la siguiente:

```
Alerta de seguridad

Tu aplicación contiene claves de API de Google Cloud Platform (GCP) visibles. Consulta este artículo del Centro de Ayuda de Google para obtener más información.

Ubicaciones vulnerables:

    com.gymtechsoluciones.cliente.GoogleMapWork.PlaceAutocompleteAdapter->autocomplete
    com.gymtechsoluciones.cliente.GoogleMapWork.SearchPlaces->onPlaceClick

Afecta a las versiones 16 y 12 del APK.
```

Al revisar esas ubicaciones que señala, veo que aparece visible la key de maps, pero no se que debería hacer, ocultarla o cambiarla por otra cosa.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Alex, no debes escribir directamente en código tu API KEY, alguién puede obtenerla y hacer mal uso de ella, revisa los 2 primeras opciones que expongo para que "no sea visible", importante también restringir el uso de la API KEY solo para tu app.

Comment: Gracias por tu recomendación Jorge. Soy nuevo en Android. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante revisar la [documentación para el uso de claves de API](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=es-419&visit_id=637218728168710089-1085395774&rd=1), especificamente:

[Protege las claves de API](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=es-419&visit_id=637218728168710089-1085395774&rd=1#securing_an_api_key)

en tu caso estas agregando directamente la API Key directamente en tu código lo cual es incorrecto ya que esta puede ser obtenida y usada en otra aplicación

Puedes realizar las opciones:

#### [Definir el valor de tu API Key en local.properties](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277921/api-key-cuenta-de-servicio/277925#277925)

En tu archivo app/build.gradle agrega:

```
android {
     ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "myAPI_KEY", "\"MY_API_KEY\"" 
        ...
    }
     ...

}
```

Dentro del archivo `local.properties` agrega la entrada y define el valor de la API KEY :

```
MY_API_KEY="AIzaSy..............."
```

Para obtener el valor en tu aplicación de esta forma:

```
  String myApiKey = BuildConfig.myAPI_KEY;
```

#### [Descargar el archivo de configuración google-services.json y configurarlo en tu aplicación](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=es-419)

```
 //Obtiene valor de API KEY.
 String API_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);
```

---

**Sin embargo lo más importante es también que el uso de tu API KEY se encuentre restringida exclusivamente para tu aplicación android definiendo nombre del paquete y la huella digital del certificado de firma SHA-1:**

Esto lo puedes realizar desde:
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este: String myApiKey = BuildConfig.myAPI_KEY; ¿Dónde lo pego?, en "local.properties"?

Comment: Al obtener el valor en la variable myApiKey, definela en sb.append(myApiKey); en lugar de escribir el valor de la API key  directamente.